# Taking the expectation of Brownian motion cubed

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, wiener-measure

I'm just having a bit of trouble figuring out what the what the expectation of Brownian motion cubed is. I know

$E(W_t)$ = 0

$E(W_{t}^{2})$ = $t$

but what would $E(W_{t}^{3})$ (The expectation of Brownian motion cubed) be

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$EW_t^{3}=0$ because distribution of $W_t$ is symmetric about the origin.

Comment: Hi thank you for you help. I just wanted to confirm that Wt is the Wiener process

Answer (score 3):

$W_t$ is just a Normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t$. This means that its easy to even just look up its moments. All of its odd moments are $0$ and its even moments are given by
$$\mathbb{E}[W_t^{2k}] = t^{k} (2k-1)!!$$
where $(2k-1)!!$ is the product of all odd integers between $1$ and $2k-1$.